# What happens to files in folder when you switch tags using Git?

Tags: git, version-control, tags

I have a folder with a git repository on my computer. When I checkout the latest code I am able to see all the newest files and changes. If I want to go back and look at a previous tag, I run the command

```
git checkout tag_name
```

In a hypothetical situation, some of my files may be removed, and some just revert to older versions.

Are all the versions of the files on my hard drive? Where do they go when I switch between tags? Are the files that have been added simply hidden?

Also, and this may be a separate question, how is it able to switch between tags so quickly when other VCS take significantly longer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git works off of deltas (the differences between the versions). Instead of getting the entire new (or old) version, it just edits the files on disk using the deltas from the different versions. So if you only edit 1 line in a million line document, it only has to get that 1 line change from the git server, and make it to the local version of that file.

For more information look at [Delta Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding)

> Git stores each revision of a file as a unique blob object. The relationships between the blobs can be found through examining the tree and commit objects. Newly added objects are stored in their entirety using zlib compression. This can consume a large amount of disk space quickly, so objects can be combined into packs, which use delta compression to save space, storing blobs as their changes relative to other blobs. [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29#Data_structures)

Comment: When they talk about storage, they are talking about your local repository. Git is distributed, so each repository contains the entire history.

Comment: you are right, for some reason I got to thinking about SVN, I removed that last line talking about the client

Answer (score 0):

It matches working directory to your branch name and new changes stores in project history, so nothing is deleted.
If you working on branch A and switch to B while someone makes changes to A and then you want to go back so to see latest changes from A you have to pull but first push your changes to A.